# Apple Mail - block incoming mail at certain hours

Tags: mail.app, productivity

The question kind of speaks for itself. I want to find a handy way to block new mail from coming in, to avoid distractions.

I was thinking of creating a cronjob that enables and disables firewall rules on my MacBook a few times a day, but maybe there are other ways?

I could also block the traffic on the router, but the idea is that while mail is blocked on the computer, I don't want to block it on mobile devices.

What do you think would be the best solution?

Even better would be if we could send and out of office or other gentile reminder that we only answer mail 2 times a day during 12-13h and 16-17h for example.

But this is not so important, more like an experiment.

Update: I want to find a solution that can be applied company wide. So all desktops cannot receive new email during certain hours.

Comment: Just close Mail and turn of Mail notifications?

Comment: When you changed the question to be for a whole business it changed this question from a notification question to a network level blocking service question. I'd suggest getting a fancy router and block traffic from the mail provider or the incoming mail port. Keep in mind that the mail server should be outside the network so it can continue to get mail while the staff machines don't get it. This question is better suited for the networking exchange at this point

Comment: You're right. Basically I wanted to see what our options were, but it doesnt look like there are many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your machine in do not disturb mode when you want to get some work done: http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/10/turn-off-notification-center-in-os-x-temporarily/

Comment: This is a good idea. Will try it out.

Comment: Let me know how you go. I use it when I'm at work so I don't get personal notifications

Comment: if this worked for you please mark it as the answer to your question

Comment: This had worked, but I want a solution that I can implement company-wide. Will update the question.

Comment: I have accepted this answer as it is the best solution for individuals, and no alternatives came out. Obviously we can limit the internet connection, but that would cause other difficulties as well (no email in case of emergency).